# Creating a table dynamically in Android app just like you would create one in Ms word - Java

Tags: java, android

I have searched almost all keywords possible next to what am looking for. Well, I wasn't lucky enough to find it, so here I am now, what's my question?
My question is, is it possible to create a table in an Android app dynamically, say I have textViews for the columns then have the rows editable (editText), that is when you want the user to fill-in the table. I would appreciate some advice/guidance/help on this.

Like this one:

[image: an example of a table created in Ms Word]